# Imported ActiveX controls are non-visual

Tags: delphi, import, activex, controls

I have imported ActiveX controls before and were able to use them same as regular VCL controls. Every now and again I bump into a control that imports fine but doesn't show up at run-time and only show a little block in the designer.

The latest one is an ActiveX wrapper for the Scintilla editor and it shows me a grey block 100 pixels wide and 41 pixels high with the control icon on it. At run-time there's nothing, so it baiscally acts like a non-visual component even though it's supposed to be an edit control.

My questions are:

1. Has anyone else seen this?
2. Is this a known issue with Delphi's ActiveX support, or is it more likely an issue with the control itself?

Comment: Which Scintilla ActiveX wrapper are you using?

Comment: The Editawy OCX wrapper from http://www.mewsoft.com/Downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen this behavior, I suspect it's a problem with the control.

Comment: It's a VB control and hasn't been updated in a while, so I figured it probably should be usable. After posting the question, I also tried to import the control in both Delphi 2006 and Delphi 7 and neither even creates a control wrapper. So you're probably right.